# Which is the best method to Receive and Send Volume of Bytes between threads on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, bluetooth, message-passing

I am developing a Bluetooth based Android application. The Bluetooth Module is attached to an embedded device which will transmit both fixed sized packets and row bytes of huge size. Multiple threads needs to send and receive data to and from the socket at the same time. Which is the best method(design pattern) to implement this problem?
I am using singleton buffers to share data between threads. But it is causing huge overloads as I have to instantly process the received data. Also I am not able to send data from a thread while another one is receiving(It could be a logical error, I will try to resolve it).
I need advice on the fastest and optimized method to implement this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: `"Multiple threads needs to send and receive data to and from the socket at the same time"` one thread cannot write and read data at the same time - what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't mean one thread sending and receiving data at same time. But a thread thread need to send data while another one is receiving. If it is not possible, I can solve it by adding a queue to handle the "sends". My concern is the overload the design is creating and I need advice on sharing data between threads in an optimum way

Comment: tried `Piped[Input/Output]Stream`?

Comment: What data you are sending? if you are sending only the indication commands you can create multiple characteristics in the firmware side as one character is used to send the data and one character is used to receive the data. You can receive the data and add it to queue for processing instead of processing directly. No problem if you send and receive the data in the same thread.

Comment: The firmware side is not in my control. But I can identify the stream from the first eight bytes. Which is the best method to take the socket data to multiple threads. I am using singleton buffer. Is it a good practice? Or I should go for message handlers?

Comment: @pskink, I did not try piped IO, is it a standard practice to use pipes to share data between threads?

Comment: what is your current code? post some lines

Comment: @pskink, I have opened a socket. and I am reading the data to a singleton byte[] array. All my threads from different activities are accessing data from this singleton byte array. Is this the right method to share data between threads running on various activities?

Comment: and how are you performing the access synchronization?

Comment: I am using a singleton variable which keeps track of the current request being serviced. The embedded device stays on a particular mode until I send the next request, based on which I can assume the characteristics of data being received.